# You are here links

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to do links of pages that will tell where you are. In other words something like this;

You are here: ASP Free Forums > Programming > ASP Development >

I am using ASP.net c#.

Any suggestions of how I can do this.

Comment: i think `sitemappath` control will help.......

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in ASP.NET is to use a SiteMapPath control:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="Breadcrumb" runat="server">
</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add breadcrumb navigation, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx for a tutorial.

Note the above link is for ASP.Net. Your question states ASP.net, but your tags refer to classic asp. The link above works for ASP.Net. Look under "Step 4: Adding Breadcrumb Navigation".

For our site, add this control to the header `<div>`:

```
<span class="breadcrumb">
 <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
 </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

Comment: So I create an xml file which includes all the links of the pages I have and then I call this file from the master page, right?

Comment: or else I can use the feature in asp itself, like the example you  have shown.

Comment: No you only need the xml file if you want to create a menu, for just the breadcrumb you only need the SiteMapPath control.

Comment: ok ok. So if I have a master page, can I add the breadcrumb just in the header of the master page and then inherit from it?